# Magento 2: Advanced JS Bundling Automate

Tags: magento2, requirejs, bundle, requirejs-config.js, automation

I am implementing Advanced JS Bundling in my Magento 2.3.2 EE store.
The part in which we create build.js on root by combining nodes of deps, shim, paths, and map from requirejs-config.js . I want to automate this, since manually it takes a lot of time to copy and paste these nodes to my build.js file.
Anyone made any script for this?

Comment: Not used it so not really sure how good it is but see this module https://www.weltpixel.com/magento-2-speed-optimization-advanced-js-bundling.html seems like it can autmomate the build.js compilation and a few other bits kinda interesting.

Comment: @harri sorry, I think this extension is not at all useful. I have used this in other project, while on another project done the steps manually. And I only 1 step is less if we use extension and for that step too I created my own command to overcome that difference also.

Comment: good to know ive done it manually once and now redoing it for 2.3.x wanted something similar to you. This looks cool but doesn't seem to be working for me: https://github.com/magento/m2-devtools and the above i didnt want to pay for ha. Thanks for heads up tho.

Comment: Hahaha. Yup I have used both (extension and by manual) and manual seems to be really good option. Didn't know about the github one. Do you have skype id?

Comment: Yeah it is live:harri_392

Comment: @Arsalan Ul Haq, I have manged to copy the nodes into my build.js file. I am facing an issue with some dependencies that were already included in some bundle are loading separately as seen in the browser console. Could you please share yours insights into this?

Comment: You should first check which dependencies are causing issue. Comment out the nodes in build.js which have issue. Then you would have debug the js files of the node that you commented.

Comment: @Arsalan Ul Haq, thanks. I am looking for a script to automate aggregating the configuration nodes from reuirejs-config.js into build.js. Can you recommend a script if you know any?

Comment: Sorry. I am also looking for same automation script.